# How to get value of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have table, where each `<tr>` contains different value and im confused how should i Get value from each`<tr>` or get value of all `<td>` which is in `<tr>`  and send to my Controller, when i submit button.
Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction!

```js
$(function() {

  $('#ResultProduct').on("click", ".SubmitRMA", function() {

    var rows = $(this).closest("tr").next().find("select").serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '@Url.Action("AnmodOmRMA", "User")',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: rows,
      success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody id="ResultProduct">

  <tr class="RMAJS">
    <td id="varnummer" name="varnummer">SH2800</td>
    <td id="Beskrivelse" name="Beskrivelse">some text</td>
    <td id="AntalVarer" name="AntalVarer">1</td>
    <td id="PrisPrStk" name="PrisPrStk">50</td>
    <td id="PostingDate" name="PostingDate">2018-12-06</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="section">
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="">- Vælg årsag -</option>
        <option value="1">Forkert vare bestilt (fejlbestilling)</option>
        <option value="2">Forkert vare modtaget (fejllevering)</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="">- Jeg forventer -</option>
        <option value="1">Kreditnota</option>
        <option value="2">Reparation</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input name="Telefonnummer">2233018</td>
    <td><button id="btnSubmitRMA" type="submit" class="SubmitRMA">Send</button>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="RMAJS">
    <td id="varnummer" name="varnummer">61A9MAT1</td>
    <td id="Beskrivelse" name="Beskrivelse">some text two</td>
    <td id="AntalVarer" name="AntalVarer">10</td>
    <td id="PrisPrStk" name="PrisPrStk">500</td>
    <td id="PostingDate" name="PostingDate">2017-11-06</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="section">
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="">- Vælg årsag -</option>
        <option value="1">fejlbestilling</option>
        <option value="2">fejllevering</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="">- Jeg forventer -</option>
        <option value="1">Reparation</option>
        <option value="2">Kredit</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input name="Telefonnummer">1122015</td>
    <td><button id="btnSubmitRMA" type="submit" class="SubmitRMA">Send</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

JS - I tried this and its only for first `tr` which is had class `section` and its just retrive null when i check results in console.

Comment: So wait, are you trying to get hte value of all <td> elements or just the selects found in the <tr>?

Comment: @basic yes, get value of all td

Comment: i didnt understand wats the problem i just got -2 down vote !!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you put your table inside a form and then serialize it?

In your HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="form" name="form">
```

JQuery

```js
var rows = $("#form").serializeArray();
//insert the dinamic values in the form
rows.push({name: "varnumber", value: $('#varnumber').val() }); 
$.post('@Url.Action("AnmodOmRMA", "User")', rows);
```

Comment: because i loading the tables dynamically :)

Comment: I've edited the answer. I had the same problem and that was the way I solved it.

Comment: let me try it :)